# How to remap keys in Chrome OS?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remap, google-chrome-os

For someone who uses the Ctrl-W bindings in vim habitually, it is incredibly annoying to have Chrome OS ask me, "Wanna close this window, then?"

How do I remap keys in Chrome OS?  Can't find this top secret setting anywhere.

Comment: You could have a chrome extension that will enable you to bind keys. Something similar to this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-bar-keyboard-sh/omgmmhpgegfcifjmhpenmjpignkegpal?hl=en ext.

Comment: If it’s not primarily about the “annoyance” of accidentally pushing it out of habit, but you actually want to use the functions mapped to Ctrl-W, you could consider remapping it in vim using some key that’s not used by Chrome OS like here: https://superuser.com/questions/540305/vim-how-do-you-remap-the-functionality-of-ctrl-w-to-a-different-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible.

Discussion thread: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-discuss/pfAQrN0-t6c/ADp_Io32DNAJ

Answer (score 16):

Google just published these [extensions](https://github.com/google/extra-keyboards-for-chrome-os) which allow you to remap most of the keys, with some caveats.

Also, Chrome OS now* supports remapping the `Ctrl`, `Alt`, and `Search` keys to [Search/Ctrl/Alt/disabled/Esc] without any extensions.  See here: chrome://settings/keyboard-overlay#keyboard

*at least as of 33.0.1750.58 (Official Build 247552) beta

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) for vi like mappings in Chrome and the ability to remap them. Your limited to the vim/chrome commands it supports though.

So also check out [keyboard-fu](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-fu/cafiohcgicchdfciefpbjjgigbmajndb) which allows you to map keys to any Javascript snippet you want.